# Android: SQLite do not return all results

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-sqlite

I have hundred Contacts in my test telephone and tries to make a search with this code:

```
MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {"type", "_id", "detail", "optional_data", "lob_data"});
Cursor c;
String selection;
String search = selectionArgs[0].toLowerCase();
try {
    selection = "("+ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?) collate nocase";
    c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI},
            selection,
            new String[]{"%"+search+"%"},
            null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    c.moveToNext();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            Object[] rowObject = new Object[] {"Contact", c.getString(0), c.getString(1), null, imageToByte(c.getString(2))};
            cursor.addRow(rowObject);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG, "URI problem with Contacts: "+e);
}
```

If I search it do not return all result. As an example, one contact (Alexander Hall) will appear if I search for ***'and'***, ***'der'*** or ***'all'*** but do not appear if I search for ***'ale'***, ***'lex'***, ***'xan'*** or ***'hal'***. If the letters is over four in any search I get no answer at all, if someone could explain this logic to me I would be really happy.

I would also add I get different result from a search with different sort parameters, still, if I do a null search I get everyone so it do not seem to be a problem with a maximum number of search results.

Any help would be really useful, thanks.

Comment: do you want sqlitecode to store and fetch data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud try to make iterator for cursor

```js
try {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        ...
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

And your code after fixed:

```js
MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {"type", "_id", "detail", "optional_data", "lob_data"});
Cursor c;
String selection;
String search = selectionArgs[0].toLowerCase();
try {
    selection = "("+ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?) collate nocase";
    c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI},
            selection,
            new String[]{"%"+search+"%"},
            null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    //c.moveToNext();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Object[] rowObject = new Object[] {"Contact", c.getString(0), c.getString(1), null, imageToByte(c.getString(2))};
            cursor.addRow(rowObject);
        //c.moveToNext();
    }
}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG, "URI problem with Contacts: "+e);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I really did a stupid misstake. Thanks!